# Assistance with TrnCodeCode values in JackHenry-jxchange DMZ

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

I am attempting to update an old interface with JackHenry that was previously using a code when posting a transaction to an account that is now throwing several error messages concerning fees.  I'm not trying to add a fee specific transaction but an initial draw on a loan/Line of Credit.  I have tried using the ParmValSrch API call but for the particular element of TrnCodeCode, it returns no results.  If anyone may know how to obtain a list of transaction codes for the DMZ, it would be greatly appeciated.

I have tried using the ParmValSrch API call but for the particular element of TrnCodeCode, it returns no results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The value is actually TranCodeCode not TrnCodeCode. As detailed on our entry for the ParmValSrch API. The message brief below spells out all available elements that may be defined via the ParmValSrch API.

https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/parmvalsrch/